# iterating through "IN" clause in SQL without a loop

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to iterate through the "IN" clause in a SQL statement without having to implement some sort of loop?

My example is:

```
SELECT *
FROM store_table
WHERE store_a IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

Instead of having to list out all of the stores, is there a way to list write some sort of code that it will look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM store_table
WHERE store_a IN (1,2,...10);
```

I understand that the above is not real SQL syntax but for examples sake I wanted to use it in that manner. I know that if you wanted to view all stores there are many different ways, syntactically to do so but I am just worried for the first 100 or the last 20 or etc....

The reason I am asking this is because if you had 1000 stores and you wanted to see the first 500, you would have some pretty long and annoying code.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `store_a between 1 and 10` problem solved

Comment: Is there a way to view the last "X" amount in that list?

Comment: Generate row_number and filter the row numbers in where clause based on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the first 500 stores, then use:

```
select st.*
from (select st.*
      from store_table st
      order by store_a
     ) st
where rownum <= 500;
```

This assumes one row per "store", which makes sense for a table with that name.

In Oracle 12C+, you can use `fetch first 500 rows only` and not have to use a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use between instead of the in operator, e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM store_table
WHERE store_a BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```